# Python lxml: how to deal with encoding errors parsing xml strings?

Tags: python, postgresql, encoding, lxml, windows-1252

I need help with parsing xml data. Here's the scenario:

1. I have xml files loaded as strings to a postgresql database.
2. I downloaded them to a text file for further analysis. Each line corresponds to an xml file.
3. The strings have different encodings. Some explicitly specify **utf-8**, other **windows-1252**. There might be others as well; some don't specify the encoding in the string.
4. I need to parse these strings for data. The best approach I've found is the following:

```
encoded_string = bytes(bytearray(xml_data, encoding='utf-8'))
root = etree.fromstring(encoded_string)
```

When it doesn't work, I get two types of error messages:

```
"Extra content at the end of the document, line 1, column x (<string>, line 1)" 
# x varies with string; I think it corresponds to the last character in the line
```

Looking at the lines raising exceptions it looks like the **Extra content** error is raised by files with a **windows-1252** encoding.

I need to be able to parse every string, ideally without having to alter them in any way after download. I've tried the following:

1. Apply 'windows-1252' as the encoding instead.
2. Reading the string as binary and then applying the encoding
3. Reading the string as binary and converting it directly with `etree.fromstring`

The last attempt produced this error: `ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.`

What can I do? I need to be able to read these strings but can't figure out how to parse them. The xml strings with the windows encoding all start with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>`

Comment: `Etree.fromstring` is misnamed for Python 3 (it was named in the old 2.x days where unicode/encoding was much more nebulous than today) - it takes binary data, similar `tostring` produces binary data. So I’d have thought you would be best treating the content from postgres as binary (i.e. bytes). Note that if you’re looking at this data in e.g. Notepad++ it is perhaps disconcertingly helpful at silently managing the encoding and you just see what the resulting text is. If you can examine one that is UTF-8 as a binary data stream, might be useful to see if includes the byte order mark (BOM).

Comment: Is the table column bytea  xml or text?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @barny I view the files in vim or vscode.

Comment: @Jasen the table column is text.

Comment: you probably should also try to address whatever mechanism is putting these values into the database, to get it to behave consistently.

Comment: @Jasen it does behave consistently. The same error doesn't appear on the server. The difference is when I downloaded the data as raw text to get each xml entry on one line. That introduced all the errors I was getting.

Answer (score 0):

given that the table column is text, all the XML content is being presented to python in UTF-8, as a result attempting to parse a conflicting XML encoding attribute will cause problems.

maybe try stripping that attribute from the string.

Comment: That actually worked. Specifically I had to remove all \n literal,  \r literals, and encoding information if it's a Windows encoding. While this is great I couldn't also figure out how to do 1 or 2 fast. I tried gsed and it wouldn't remove newline characters. I manually removed them with vim using `%s/\\n//g` and `%s/\\r//g` which won't work for the biggest files.

Comment: if it has \r and \n literals its probably escaped,  you could try postgresql `decode(xmlcolumn,'escape')` which will give a `bytea` result in postgres which python will treat as `bytes` and should be able to parse as XML.

Comment: it didn't work. I get `XMLSyntaxError` exceptions that look exactly like the issue I had with \n. Does it make a difference how I exported the SQL output to a text file? I used `psql -d <database> -c "copy (select decode(<xmlcolumn>, 'escape') from <table>) where site=<site> to stdout > output.txt`

Comment: copy will add escaping

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing encoding information, newline literals and carriage return literals. Every string was parsed successfully if I opened the files returning errors in vim and ran the following three commands:

```
:%s/\\r//g
:%s/\\n//g
:%s/<?.*?>//g
```

Then lxml parsed the strings without issue.

**Update:**

I have a better solution. The problem was \n and \r literals in UTF-8 encoded strings I was copying to text files. I just needed to remove these characters from the strings with `regexp_replace` like so:

```
select regexp_replace(xmlcolumn, '\\n|\\r', '', 'g') from table;
```

now I can run the following and read the data with lxml without further processing:

```
psql -d database -c "copy (select regexp_replace(xml_column, '\\n|\\r', '', 'g') from resource ) to stdout" > output.txt
```